# Angular 11 + express locals variables

Tags: nodejs, angular, express, variables

Tengo un problema con locals variables en express + node, hago res.locals.xxx = {zzz: "yyy"}; y acto seguido res.render(fileLocation, { req }, function (err, html), pero en Angular 11, en un componente, declaro declare var locals: any; y luego hago un console.log(locals);
, esto lanza un error de undefined. He intentado:
-declare var _locals: any;
-declare var local: any;
-declare var _local: any;
-declare var xxx: any;

Pero todos dan error, ¿Cual es la forma correcta de capturar las variables locales de express con Angular? estas variables son diferentes con cada request.

EDIT:
Pondré lo que he podido hacer con el mínimo de código posible, la parte del server se compondrá de dos archivos principales, el server.ts y el app.ts

**server.ts**

```
import * as https from "https";  
import app from "./app";  
const fs = require('fs');  
https.createServer({  
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),  
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')  
},app).listen(8000);
```

**app.ts**

```
import * as express from "express";
import { enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";
enableProdMode();
class App {
    public app;
    constructor() {
        this.app = express();
        this.app.use(express.json());
        this.app.route("*").post((req, res) => {
            this.proxyRequest(req, res);
        });
    }  
    
    proxyRequest(req, res) {
        global["thing"] = "value_thing";
        const fileLocation = Path.resolve(process.cwd(), "views") + "/index.html";
        res.render(fileLocation, { req }, function (err, html) {
            res.send(html);
        });
    }
}  

export default new App().app;
```

Y en un componente Angular normal lo siguiente:

**index.component.ts**

```
declare var global: any;

@Component({
    selector: "app-index",
    templateUrl: "./index.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./index.component.scss"],
})  

export class IndexComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor(){}  

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(global.thing || global["thing"]);
    }
}
```

Quiero sustituir global["thing"] = "value_thing" por res.locals.thing= "value_thing"; en el mismo lugar u otra alternativa en res.render(fileLocation, { req } por res.render(fileLocation, { req, thing: "value_thing" } y recuperar este valor en index.component exactamente igual que he hecho con el global, pero con variables que desaparezcan después de cada request.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Angular se ejecuta en el navegador y express en el servidor... las variables no se comparten de ningún modo

Comment: pero si utilizo globals en express si que las puedo recuperar desde Angular, basicamente estoy usando espress como SSR, pero las variables globales dejan pérdidas de memoria y quería hacer lo mismo pero con variables que desaparezcan después de cada request, pero no se como hacerlo
lo utilizo así global["a"] y en angular hago esto declare var global: any; y luego global.a y la puedo recuperar

Comment: ¿Sin ver ejemplos de código es complicado aonsejarte... puedes crear un [mcve]?

Comment: crearé un ejemplo mínimo y lo publicaré aquí cuando lo tenga, muchas gracias

Comment: He creado un ejemplo mínimo de loq ue tengo y de lo que necesitaría

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La verdad es que no hay mucha documentación oficial sobre como resolver este problema, pero finalmente he conseguido hacer funcionar lo que quieres. Para implementarlo necesitamos completar 3 pasos:

##### Express

Necesitamos pasar a la parte de Angular los datos. Esto se consigue mediante los parámetros del método `render`:

```
server.post('*', (req, res) => {
    // Obtenemos los datos que queremos mandar al componente
    // aquí simplemente estoy usando un valor fijo de prueba
    const datos = { data: "Test" };

    res.render(indexHtml, {
      req,
      // declaramos un proveedor de los datos 
      providers: [
        { provide: "message", useValue: datos }
      ]
    });
  });
```

##### Código en Angular: Añadir la importación de los módulos ...TransferStateModule

Tenemos que añadir a los `imports` del módulo del lado servidor `ServerTransferStateModule`, para poder usar un servicio que nos será necesario

Al módulo del lado del navegador tenemos que añadirle su equivalente: `BrowserTransferStateModule`.

Una vez tenemos completada esta parte, en el Componente necesitamos hacer algo como lo siguiente:

##### Angular: Inyección de los datos en los Componentes

```js
  constructor(
      @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
      // opcional, puesto que sólo se provee en el lado servidor
      @Optional() @Inject('message') public message: {data: any},
      private readonly transferState: TransferState
    ) {

    const storeKey = makeStateKey<{data: any}>('message');
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      // el segundo parámetro es el valor por defecto, si no se
      // proveyó desde el servidor un valor
      this.message = this.transferState.get(storeKey, {data: "default"});
    } else {
      this.transferState.set(storeKey, this.message);

    }
  }
```

Explicación del código: El HTML del componente se va a calcular dos veces:

- en el lado del servidor, con lo que el parámetro `message` tendrá el valor esperado y el HTML que se envía en la respuesta mostrará ese dato.
- en el navegador, cuando se haga la "rehidratación". Ahí ese parámetro no existe y será `null`, por lo que el HTML será actualizado automáticamente con ese valor.

Si no usáramos `transferState`, veríamos un parpadeo en el navegador cuando se carga el HTML: durante un instante se mostrará el mensaje y casi instantáneamente se eliminará.

La forma de mantener ese valor es transferir el estado desde el servidor al cliente y la forma de hacerlo es la que se ve en el constructor:

- si estamos en el lado servidor (`isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)` es falso), guardamos el estado.
- si estamos en el navegador, recuperamos el estado.

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo, esto me ayuda muchísimo